# Vue 3 - Binding multiple classes to one condition

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

From [the docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/class-and-style.html#object-syntax), it shows that we can bind classes to conditions like so:

```
<div
  class="static"
  :class="{ active: isActive, 'text-danger': hasError }"
></div>
```

What if I want to bind two classes to the same condition, would this work? Would there be a shorter way?

```
<div
  class="static"
  :class="{ active: isActive,  active: isSelectable }"
></div>
```

Comment: `:class="{ active: isActive || isSelectable }"` you can also separate that out into a helper method if the complexity grows too much.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to bind multiple classes to the same condition. There's nothing preventing you from doing it like this if you wanted to ..

```
<div
  class="static"
  :class="{ 'class-1 class-2': condition }"
></div>
```

Comment: What if I want to concat class name with variable name? Like this `:class="{ `fa-${item.icon}`: 2 == 2 }"`

Comment: @MohammadAyoubKhan then you can use the dynamic property syntax like so -
:class="{ [\`fa-${item.icon}\`] : 2 == 2 }"
Ternaries are also good here inside the [ ] declaration.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `||` and `&&` to combine conditions:

```
   <div
      class="static"
      :class="{ active: isActive || isSelectable }"
    ></div>
```